# How to give two html elements in the same column?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have to insert a check box and one more field into an existing `<td>`. However, these fields are currently not showing on one line. Please find the html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Timer<p/>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox" size="30"/>
   </td>
    <td>
      Please check the box
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

This outputs something like this:

> `Jill   Smith`
>
> `Timer Please check the box`
>
> `[]`

Here "Timer" and check box aren't on the same line (inside the same `<td>`).

Can anybody please help me out?

PS: I can't change the already available table format.

Reason for timer inside p:
Timer is a dynamic filed which have the count start from 20 to 0.
So I have  to use `<p>` element id inside JavaScript which I didn't mention here.

Comment: use `display-inline` or `float:left`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8nqzuddo/2/

Comment: put it in the <p> tag like this <p>Timer <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox" size="30"/><p/>

Comment: I have to  show  <p> timer </p>  timer which starts at 20 to reduces to zero @Hamza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
td p,td input{float:left}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Timer<p/>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox" size="30"/>
   </td>
    <td>
      Please check the box
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
td p,td input{display:inline}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Timer<p/>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox" size="30"/>
   </td>
    <td>
      Please check the box
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
td p,td input{display:inline-block}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Timer<p/>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox" size="30"/>
   </td>
    <td>
      Please check the box
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Timer<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox" size="30"/><p/>
      
   </td>
    <td>
      Please check the box
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Update (comment request)

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p style="float:left">Timer<p/>
      <input  style="float:left" type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox" size="30"/>
   </td>
    <td>
      Please check the box
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

adding a class

```css
.inline{
    display:inline
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p class=inline>Timer<input  class=inline type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox" size="30"/><p/>
      
   </td>
    <td>
      Please check the box
    <td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think he just didnt know that p forces a new line. So i think the first 3 Code Snippet wont help him ;)

Comment: @tambo if it is a css changes it will affect whole page right How to make it for only these fields

Answer (score 1):

`<p>` does force a new line, so the Checkbox is in the next line.  Try `<span>Timer</span>`

---

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">Text</label>
```

Would be the best option, since now you can also click on the Name of the Checkbox, to check the box.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap each item in different cell, it'll help you in that case.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Timer
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox"/>
    </td>
    <td>
       Please check the box
    </td>
</tr>
```

Or, if you need checkbox and label in the same cell

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Timer
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox"/>
    </td>
    <td>
       Please check the box
    </td>
</tr>
```

Or even

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"> <!-- colspan is 2 because you have two cols in your table -->
        Timer
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" name="checkBox"/>
       Please check the box
    </td>
</tr>
```

"P" is block element and creates new block and new line as result.

Comment: I want the id of timer that's why used inside <p>

Comment: Ok, wrap timer into span with 'id' that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "paragraph"

> < p>

element , near the text "Timer" from the above code. :)

Answer (score 0):

**P is a block level element. What that DTD is saying is that `<p>` tags can only contain inline elements.**

you can overide this with

```
p{
display:inline-block!important;
}
```